# I set True=False and I can't undo it

Tags: python, python-2.x

I was in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/be-the-first-1-leave-only-the-first-truthy) code golf thread where I learned in Python 2 you can set `True=False`. Now that I would like to go back to the real world I want `True` to be regular old True but if I run `True=True` python diverts the assignment `True` to `False`.

I realize I can assign `True=1` and things will mostly work normally, but is there a way to reset `True` without reseting the kernel?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
del True
```

This removes the binding you created for `True`, unhiding the built-in. This is a slightly more thorough way to undo your mistake than assigning anything to `True`, although it usually won't matter.

Comment: upvote for the _correct_ way to do it. Also it's golfier than mine so also +1 :P

Answer (score 7):

A lot of things return `True`. Do `True = 1 == 1`.

Moral of the story: Don't run code-golf code in production environments! You're lucky that that was all you did, a lot of the stuff there is even worse... And I know, coming from PPCG :P

Comment: @dylnan No problem :P Consider becoming an active member of PPCG! It's fun! :D (:P)

Comment: Yeah, just realized that myself and found it funny enough to be worth an answer. (Originally I abstained because user2357112 showed that these are all rather wrong.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann The real problem isn't that these are "wrong", but more so that these are not as short as the other one and thus can be golfed. :P

Comment: Well you can do `True=0<1`, that's just as short as `del True`.

Answer (score 6):

Just a fun one:

```
True = not True
```

Answer (score 2):

Set it to exactly what you want:

```
True = bool(1)
```

Here's some fiddling in interactive mode to illustrate what you're seeing:

```
>>> True
True
>>> True=False
>>> True
False
>>> True=True
>>> True
False
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>> True = bool(1)
>>> True
True
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>>
```